# CameraRoll api not returning all pictures in album

Tags: react-native, camera-roll

I'm using the CameraRoll api (getPhotos) to fetch pictures from a specific album. Unfortunately, when I call getPhotos (with any combination of first:number) params, I don't always get all the pictures in the album.

I usually have to make the getPhotos call a number of times (by pressing g a button I added to the app) to request all the pictures. I'm wondering if this has something to do with the *cursor* attribute returned to the callback after a successful getPhotos request.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, I have the same problem here